# Record must end with an empty line - missing changetype (LDIF)

Tags: ldif

I tried putting the following LDIF file in Apache Directory Studio, but it complained that the record must end with an empty line. Do you know why?

```
dn: CN=serialNumber,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=myorg,DC=com
changetype: ntdsSchemaAdd
lDAPDisplayName: serialNumber
adminDisplayName: serialNumber
description: Token serial number
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
oMSyntax: 64
isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet: FALSE
isSingleValued: TRUE
searchFlags: 0
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeID: 1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554.56278.0.46625.19000.45599.15687267.6686356.2.1
schemaIDGUID:: 3U7SiIq9SByhs/i1Z6fEsw==
```

Answer (score 1):

The LDIF specification (RFC 2849) says that a line must end with a new line character (CR or LF).  There must be a blank line after each record since this is how they are delimited.

By the way: the changetype `ntdsSchemaAdd` isn't supported by Apache Directory Studio. Only standard changetypes (`add`, `modify`, `delete`, `moddn`) are supported.

Comment: But how can a line not end with a new line character? Is this something to do with the different new line standards across platforms?